# Cannot get assembly version for footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, versioning

I'm using the automatic build versioning mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/c-displaying-the-build-date) (not the selected answer but the answer that uses the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` technique). I'm doing this in the footer of my Site.Master file in MVC 2. My code for doing this is as follows:

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="emailto:webmaster@foo.com">webmaster@foo.com</a> - Copyright © 2005-<%= DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() %>, foo LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    - Version: <%= Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString() %>
</div>
```

The exception I get is a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because `GetEntryAssembly()` returns `NULL`. My other options don't work either. `GetCallingAssembly()` always returns "4.0.0.0" and `GetExecutingAssembly()` always returns "0.0.0.0". When I go look at my DLLs, everything is versioning as I would expect. But I cannot figure out how to access it to display in my footer!!

Comment: `Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).GetName().Version.ToString()` also returns "0.0.0.0"

Comment: GetEntryAssembly() also can return null when the assembly is called from unmanaged code  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx

Comment: and w3wp.exe is indeed unmanaged, Module 'w3wp.exe' does not contain a CLI header

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That's because `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is returning null: there *is no* "entry" assembly in an ASP.NET site (because the .NET framework is hosted in the w3wp.exe process). `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is used to get the .exe assembly that you launched from (usually in a console or Windows application)

The reason `Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())` is returning an assembly with version "0.0.0.0" is because ASP.NET compiles your Site.Master file into a temporary assembly under your "ASP.NET Temporary Files" folder. `this` is a reference to the "generated" class.

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is *basically* the same as `Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())` (except it also works when there is no "this" (e.g. in static methods).

The best way would be use explicity use a type that you *know* exists in the assembly you're after. As an example, I assume your "Site.Master" has a code-behind file that is compiled into the assembly. You can use that instead:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Site)).GetName().Version.ToString()
```

(assuming the name of the class is `Site`)

Comment: This works! `<%= Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)).GetName().Version.ToString() %>`

Comment: Interesting, I performed a little test by creating an HtmlHelper extension that has the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() call in it and I was able to call that from my Site.Master and it worked just fine! This actually is surprising to me because I modified my csproj file to have it compile my views. Am I misunderstanding what that setting does? I thought that removed all of the temporary assemblies and whatnot?

Comment: Views are always compiled, the difference is you can either compile everything up-front in one go or you can compile them on-demand when the site is first accessed. Either way, they'll still be compiled into a separate DLL.

Comment: Oh, I just assumed that they went into the main assembly when I compiled them up-front. Thanks for that clarification. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Just as another solution that people may be interested in, I've concocted these helpers to help with this problem:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    private static string _CachedCurrentVersionDate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the Current Version from the AssemblyInfo.cs file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string CurrentVersion(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        try
        {
            var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            return version.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return "?.?.?.?";
        }
    }

    public static string CurrentVersionDate(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_CachedCurrentVersionDate == null)
            {
                // Ignores concurrency issues - assuming not locking this is faster than 
                // locking it, and we don't care if it's set twice to the same value.
                var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
                var ticksForDays = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * version.Build; // days since 1 January 2000
                var ticksForSeconds = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 2 * version.Revision; // seconds since midnight, (multiply by 2 to get original)
                _CachedCurrentVersionDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add(new TimeSpan(ticksForDays + ticksForSeconds)).ToString();
            }

            return _CachedCurrentVersionDate;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Unknown Version Date";
        }
    }
}
```

This allows consumption as follows in your footer:

```
Version: <%= Html.CurrentVersion() %> from <%= Html.CurrentVersionDate() %>
```

Comment: Adjustments due to daylight saving time isn't accounted for in the time calculation.

Answer (score 8):

You can:

e.g in your Application_Start method in Global.asax file add

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("Version", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
}
```

in HTML show it by

```
<div><% =HttpContext.Current.Application["Version"].ToString() %></div>
```

**ALSO** Change Assembly version to 1.0.0.* by going to
- Project properties > Application > Assembly Information and assembly version is shown as 1.0.0.0 - change it to 1.0.0.*

this will give you some versioning

Comment: This becomes testable by adding various tricks/complexity though.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have Global.asax in place, it could be a good place to store version globally once.

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public static readonly Version Version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
}
```

Your view:

```
<div>- Version: @YourNamespace.Global.Version</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not testable.