# Running an action method on every view

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to show the version info of the current project on every page.

The way I do it in the moment is like this:

Inside the Index method of my homecontroller:

```
ViewBag.Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Inside the _layout.cshtml(masterpage):

```
@ViewBag.Version
```

The Problem here is, it will only displayed once, but I want to display the Version on every page/view.

This is my routing configuration:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }


        );
    }
```

Do I have to change something here ?

Ty for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

on the `_Layout.cshtml` view?

MVC has a different launch context and a work around is needed to text the version:

```
@typeof(HomeController).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

`HomeController` could be replaced with any other type in the assembly the MVC application assembly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815324/cannot-get-assembly-version-for-footer) for more info.

Comment: because it shows only 0.0.0.0 instead of the real defined version number

Comment: Have you defined the version in `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: Yes, under the Properties folder (location of the file) and it is defined as the following: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.2")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.2")]

Comment: @user254197 try using the full namespace: `W4K.mvc.Controllers.HomeController` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in the Layout.

```
<label>@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version</label>
```

Comment: It shows only 0.0.0.0 instead of the real defined version number