# Macro for build date in C#

Tags: c#, macros, visual-c#-express-2010

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/c-displaying-the-build-date) deals with the retrieval of an app's build date in C#, but there's gotta be a more efficient way to do it. So here's a little idea I had...

Does Visual C# have a compiler macro that will insert the build date on a given position when the project is being compiled? It would be nice if the compiler could auto-generate the build date that will be displayed in my app's About screen. After all, having to change the date manually every time is a pain in the neck.

Comment: What's wrong with the "the old way" in your 'related question' link? It's built into Visual C#, works fine, takes 3 lines of code, and is dead easy to do.

Comment: Three lines of code? The accepted answer is about twenty lines of code. Not too efficient considering that if all that could potentially be replaced by a macro that apparently doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no.
Here is the list of c# preprocessor directives: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(vs.71).aspx

We are using msbuild with generate assemblyinfo task for such a thing. it is easy and works like a charm.

PS
Also you can modify project file *.proj and add this custom task into it.