# how do I add a Publish date to a project I'm publishing in vs2010?

Tags: c#, .net, publish

I know I can add a version number  to the "help" menu

application.pruductversion

but I do not know how I can add the date  when the application was  published

Answer (score 9):

If you want to display the build date of your assembly this should do it in the most cases:

```
public static DateTime GetBuildDate()
{
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    return File.GetLastWriteTime(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path))
        );
}
```

There's also another way determining the real compile/build date "the hard way" here on SO:

- [Displaying the build date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/c-displaying-the-build-date/1600990#1600990)

Answer (score 1):

Use AssemblyInfo file, for more information: [AssemblyInfo on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.assemblyinfo.aspx)

If you are looking for adding a version number into the add/remove programs menu, you need to modify the msi file using something like SuperOrca or programmatically using something like Phavant MSI (google it)