# Force AssemblyVersion("1.0.*") to observe DST when populating Revision?

Tags: .net, assemblies, timestamp, version, dst

It seems that, when using the following syntax in a C# project's AssemblyInfo.cs file, the Revision value doesn't observe Daylight Saving Time (it *does* use local time).

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

Is there a way that I can make .NET consider DST when converting the above into the timestamp?

Comment: If it doesn't already, I don't believe you could make it. The attribute and how it generates the version, is internal BCL code that can't be controlled outside of Microsoft.

Comment: I've been trying to find where *anything's* documented about the numbers that are automatically chosen using that format. The only related documentation I've found suggests that the numbers are arbitrary - that they're not *meant* to necessarily be a date and time. Do you have any docs specifying that they *should* be?

Comment: @Jon - The description in the attribute constructor documentation does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

Comment: Or maybe, if you need granular control over the assembly versioning scheme, you can use AssemblyFileVersion instead. You can refer to this article: http://www.all-things-sharp.com/2011/08/custom-assembly-versioning-with-vs-2010.html

Comment: @Oded: Ah, thanks. I wonder why that wasn't mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Related link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date

Comment: The 'assembly' tag is for low level programming, not for .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make .NET consider DST when converting the asterisks into the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, wrong question, you should have asked how to get it to use UTC.  Because if you don't know where the build server is located then the timestamp you get doesn't mean anything anyway.  If you *do* know where it is located then you know enough to reverse engineer the DST time too with the TimeZoneInfo class.