# Can I make a C# compiler store the time of compilation into assembly?

Tags: c#, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying the build date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date)

I'd like to be able to retrieve the moment when a specific C# assembly was compiled so that I can show the time of compilation along with the version number.

Is it possible to tell a C# compiler to somehow embed the time at which compilation happened into the assembly?

Comment: maybe use a oldskool stopwatch?

Comment: a quick idea, use a T4 template that generates a `const DateTime CompiledAt = <#= DateTime.Now #>`

Comment: Anything wrong with using the file create date?

Comment: @oded: very unreliable. You can't guarantee this date is preserved. The first exemple that comes to my mind is if you publish/download the file from/to an http server