# How can I display in my ExtJS web-app the sencha app build timestamp

Tags: extjs, gradle, sencha-cmd

I am currently building my sencha application using sencha app build inside of gradle.

When the build occurs I want to set information such as the timestamp of the build so that it can be referenced and outputted in the built web application. I presumed that sencha cmd would store some details about the state of the build however can not find where to reference that information in any documentation.

If build information is not saved by Sencha Cmd, I presume that this information should be passed in from the Gradle build process?

- I found page on how to do this via gradle however was more interested in a sencha based solution. [Displaying version and date of build in the xhtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426723/displaying-version-and-date-of-build-in-the-xhtml-page)

Thank you for any help.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the deeper dive into [Sencha cmd here](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_build.html) 
In your build.xml add an -after-page task to append it to the generated javascript file
Try the following which will put the timestamp string and then you can use it:

```
<target name="-after-page">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="APP_TIMESTAMP" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"
    </tstamp>

    <!--
    The build.classes.file property holds the full path to the "all-classes.js"
    file so we use that variable rather than hard-code the name.
    -->
    <move file="${build.classes.file}" tofile="${build.classes.file}.tmp"/>

    <concat destfile="${build.classes.file}">
        <header filtering="no" trimleading="yes">
            var applicationTimestamp = "${THISYEAR}";
        </header>
        <fileset file="${build.classes.file}.tmp"/>
    </concat>

    <delete file="${build.classes.file}.tmp" />
</target>
```

Comment: Really elegant solution, was expecting a config but this is just as neat. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the above example. it should be 
var applicationTimestamp = "${APP_TIMESTAMP}" instead of "${THISYEAR}"