# Why does this code for manipulating PE file header use such strange offset value?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++

[Here's a piece of code for obtaining the time when a .NET assembly was built](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990). Note:

```
const int c_LinkerTimestampOffset = 8;
```

and later:

```
int secondsSince1970 = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(b, i + c_LinkerTimestampOffset);
```

this code extracts the `TimeDateStamp` member of [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is stored inside the assembly. The structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_FILE_HEADER {
    WORD  Machine;
    WORD  NumberOfSections;
    DWORD TimeDateStamp;
    DWORD PointerToSymbolTable;
    DWORD NumberOfSymbols;
    WORD  SizeOfOptionalHeader;
    WORD  Characteristics;
} IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, *PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER;
```

and `WORD` is two bytes and should be two-bytes aligned. When I compile the following code with Visual C++ 10:

```
IMAGE_FILE_HEADER header;
char* start = (char*)&header;
char* field = (char*)(&header.TimeDateStamp);
int diff = field - start;
```

`diff` equals `4` as I personally expected.

Is that a bug in the C# code? Why is offset value of `8` used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its used to skip the additional signature, as `i` contains the offset to the NT headers, not the file image header (see the [formal PE structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)):

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_NT_HEADERS {
    DWORD Signature; //<- we need to skip this
    IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 OptionalHeader;
} IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32, *PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32;
```

so the actual sum is `sizeof(WORD /* FileHeader.Machine */) + sizeof(WORD /* FileHeader.NumberOfSections */) + sizeof(DWORD /* Signature */)`

bottom line, not a bug, just some magic to skip a bit of structure nesting/inlining.

Answer (score 0):

> DWORD is a int unsigned value, 4 bytes.

The C# code is not correct, it reads 8 bytes. I think it should be 4.

```
int secondsSince1970 = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(b, i + c_LinkerTimestampOffset);
```

I had written a PE reader few days ago. I used this for the "Image File Header":

```
public class IMAGE_FILE_HEADER 
{
     public UInt16 Machine;
     public UInt16 NumberOfSections;
     public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
     public UInt32 PointerToSymbolTable;
     public UInt32 NumberOfSymbols;
     public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
     public UInt16 Characteristics;
}
```

Comment: Why is `DWORD` suddenly 8 bytes?

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely getting a 8 bytes diff because you are on a 64 bit system/target platform, if you would be on a 32 bit it would have been what you expected it to be.

On 32 bit systems DWORD is defined as a uint (32bits/4bytes) and on 64 bit systems its a ulong (64bits/8bytes).

A WORD essentially stands for the address size of the architecture. When it was coined a WORD was 16 bits and a DWORD was a double word, 32 bits (4 bytes).

One would expect DWORD to be 64bits/8bytes on x86 systems but MS wanted to keep legacy support so it kept the old definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Nope, `DWORD` is always 4 bytes.