# Visual Studio 2013 on publish a release to update date in index.cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I have a asp.net mvc 4 application developed on Visual Studio 2013, what I need is every time I publish the application, I would like to update the date in /views/Home/index.cshtml so it updates to datetime of the release.

Example: I have this code at bottom of index.cshtml file

```
<p>&copy;2015 mysite.com | Released on 04/03/2015 12:05pm</p>
```

So this part `04/03/2015 12:05pm` need to be updated every time I do publish release.

Is this possible to be achieved? I searched it on the net and couldn't find anything helpful.

Any help out there? thanks

Comment: Perhaps this might help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx

Comment: This might also help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date)

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, This was exactly what I was looking for.