# Compile time and version output with optional command line argument

Tags: c#, build, compile-time

I have a program in C#, where I want to store the build date and version. The version is added by me, the build date should be automatically generated. Normally if I start the program, there is nothing to do with, but if I add -V option in CMD, I would like to see build date and version. How should I do this?

I need optional arguemnt and somehow get the build date while building it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there are two ways to achieve this.

**Option 1** 
Use information that is already present in the assembly like this:
[Displaying the build date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date)

**Option 2**
Define a pre-build event to generate a file (source or ressource) which is compiled into the assembly. This way you can embed any (external) information automatically - for example the svn/git version number.