# Howto set a DateTime at compiletime

Tags: c#, compile-time

Basically I need a field containing a compile timestamp. How can this be archived?

```
DateTime compileDateTime = //At Compiletime: DateTime.Now
```

The field might also be defined as a constant.

It is crucial that the field is defined at compile time. The application is executed on an embedded device in "sandbox mode". There is no access to the file system, so the assembly itself can not be loaded to retrieve the time stamp.

To make it more clear. (Since to many people where focused on retrieving the build date from the assembly) I could also ask to "hardcode" a random number for every build.

`int myConstNumberForThisBuild = //At compile-time: new Random().Next()`

Comment: One easy possibility is pre-build step generating cs-file where this constant is defined.

Comment: I guess you want the actual time at which the application was compiled?

Comment: @Sinatr or any file.  A text file.

Comment: @DavidG, please read the question! This is in no way similar to the duplicate you marked it. I ask about setting a field, not retrieving a date from another assembly.

Comment: File.GetCreationTime(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Comment: @ Narek Arzumanyan `GetCreationTime` will give date of 1st compilation not last (file creation not last modified). But `GetLastWriteTime` wil answer the question.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen -- Unfortunately, you can't ping DavidG like that.  He won't get it.  There's not way to get his attention.

Comment: I can't read the assembly at run-time (there is no acces to the file system where the application is executed (don't ask :-) )). I really need to set the value at compile (or pre-compile) time.

Comment: @roryap Yes I will get a ping!

Comment: I'm happy to re-open it for a valid reason, not heard one yet.

Comment: @Stijn Van Antwerpen looks like you don't understand what you want. A constant (which must be set before compilation) or a value (which will be calculated while running ie after compilation)

Comment: @DavidG -- Huh.  I was studying a meta post recently about who gets what ping.  I guess I misunderstood it.  I was just going off the fact that it doesn't suggest your name.  Of course, it does now that you're commenting.

Comment: @roryap It may be Mjolnir related, don't think I'd get pinged from a normal close vote.

Comment: @DavidG -- [Mjolnir](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir)?

Comment: @roryap [Mjolnir](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268608/where-did-the-use-of-the-name-mjolnir-come-from)!

Comment: If you can't read the assembly, then how can you possibly load it?

Comment: @DavidG, I don't want to load the assembly. I want to "hardcode" a value that need to be set at compile time. Like `DateTime copileTime = new DateTime(2016,05,08,14,55,...)` but I don't want to change the value by hand every time I rebuild.

Comment: So you want the compile time of some random assembly in your solution? This really doesn't make sense to me yet.

Comment: No, I want the compile time of the assembly itself.

Comment: That means you have implicit access to the file that contains the assembly, so the linked duplicate will work.

Comment: @DavidG No, it will fail on the creation of the FileStream... There is no acces to the file-system. Actually, the FileStream class is even not available in the sandbox.

Comment: The linked dupe has lots of answers that don't involve reading the file. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1601079/1663001) or some variation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15502932/1663001) for example.

Comment: That last one is indeed more the solution I was looking for. Thx! But you really don't expect us to read all replies on a post? Question and excepted answer is already a lot to process when looking trough all possible related questions...

Comment: Oh god no, we absolutely DO expect you to read them all, so yeah, please don't be so lazy.