# C# How to recognize who build the version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to attach programmer's name and build date on the tool automatically? ex. Put a file contain programmer's name in C:\, make visual studio to reference it?? Or there is a standard method to do this??

I just found how to add a build date method(https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990/1817068)

Comment: a programmer should not be performing production  builds: your CI build system should.

Comment: @MitchWheat: agree fully about standard practice, but low budget or less skilled teams might not know or care about a CI system, even lucky if some teams have an issue tracker..

Comment: If you don't have an issue tracker and no (even basic) CI, then you are not an effective team!

Comment: Source control is also a must and easy to do even for 1 person teams. That would certainly answer this question.

Comment: Just do a custom build action that would add it in assemblyinfo somewhere?

Comment: hook the build event and update the assemblinfo.cs......  perhaps AssemblyDescription and append, either the computer name, or user login, or something like that.

Comment: Showing programmer's name on the tool just provide an easy way for end users to contact the right person, the tool is internal use for other team member who can not access our source control system...