# how to get the build date (compiler time) of any .exe or .dll file with c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the build date of an `.exe` or `.dll` file.
How can I get it?

For example:

[image]

For this `.exe` I can access last modified date via:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(exefiles);
date = file.LastWriteTime;
```

How can I get the build or compile time?
For example I want to do it like this program:
[image]

Comment: If the file in question is a .net assembly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date

Comment: The last modified date IS the build date. Do you mean file version (or product version)?

Comment: I wrote this document.but I want to get build date another programs on my application.I dont want our application build date.I have to send another program paths it will return build date I want to this

Comment: as long as you are dealing with .net assemblies, use @sloth 's approach ... for arbitrary .exe or .dll files this is not possible since those files are not required to even hold that information...

Comment: please look new picture.I want to do like this program

Comment: @RufusL _The last modified date IS the build date_ not always: e.g. if you download a file, the last modified date will be download date and time

Comment: I agreed @GianPaolo

Comment: @GianPaolo - I stand corrected!

Comment: @SezerErdogan isn't the date in the second image the same as in the first?

Comment: I just tested the code in the first comment and it works great.