# I am working in MVC and I would like to implement versioning that uses the last build date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to display the version as yyyy.mm.dd of the last build date to users,
how can I accomplish this? relatively new to c#.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date

You can format the day in that manner by using: date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with ASP.NET MVC - the question would largely be the same if you were using WPF or a console project.

Comment: @Dai I think the OP wants to use MVC versioning with the build number: `api/05-04-2017/products`. However it doesn't make sense to use build number for API versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between *HttpContext* and *System.IO*, you can find the location and last modification date of any file within your website

HttpContext (aka Server) has a `MapPath()` method within it to figure out where you are, and then you can add in the relative location of a particular file.

```
    string AppRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\");
    string AppDll = AppRoot + @"bin\MyWebApp.dll";
```

System.IO can then work with that location to get all of the properties about a particular file. In your context you are looking for the *Last Modified Date*, and here is a simple method to retrieve it:

```
    public static DateTime GetLastModDate(string FilePath) {
        DateTime retDateTime;

        if (File.Exists(FilePath)) { retDateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(FilePath); } 
        else { retDateTime = new DateTime(0);  }

        return retDateTime;
    }
```

Combine these and you get

```
DateTime LastBuildDate = GetLastModDate(AppDll);
```

Comment: Just saw this, I ended up going a similar route: I grabbed the write date of the project.dll from the bin folder and converted the datetime to yyyy.mm.dd.

I used HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath to get the path

Comment: I've used this in the _AppStart_ routine and just set a variable within so that it does not have to keep getting called.

Comment: Ah that's a clever idea, thanks!