# Is there any way to determine if a .NET assembly was compiled with the "deterministic" flag?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, portable-executable

I am using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990/270348) to get the linker timestamp of a .NET assembly.

However, if the assembly was compiled as "deterministic", this value is not an accurate measure of when the assembly was built ([reference](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/deterministic-builds-in-roslyn.html)), and so I want to ignore it.

Is there any information in the PE header (or any other part of the assembly) which indicates that it's been built as "deterministic"?

Comment: If there was, I'd expect it to be an attribute contained in the `CompilerServices` namespace, but I can't see any likely suspects there.

Answer (score 1):

[NuGet Package Explorer](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/nuget-package-explorer/9WZDNCRDMDM3?hl=en-us&gl=us) can be used to find out if an assembly in a nuget package was built using the deterministic flag.

Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/blob/9fd0052b1b755866aaaa4f08867118c1929be2aa/Core/SymbolValidation/SymbolValidator.cs#L164) there seem to be multiple checks before marking an assembly/whole package to be built deterministic. Looks like they implemented everything of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990/270348) in code to find out if an assembly was build deterministic.