# Why my DLL files inside are being marked as modified in git?

Tags: c#, git, .net-6.0

I need to include some DLL files inside git. I know this is not a good practice. But this solution solves one of our problems for now.

But the problem is that, while I have not changed anything at all, and not a single line of code is modified and not even a character is modified, when I use `dotnet build` I see that git marks the output as *modified*.

I tried to compare them using Beyond Compare's Hex comparison, and here's an image of the beginning bytes:

[image]

I can't find out why it's modified. I mean, I expect `dotnet build` to be deterministic and give me the same results for the same inputs. But apparently something is changed.

Does anyone know why `dotnet build` has this behavior?

I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: my guess: it includes a _timestamp_ of when the binary was built. which, unless you have a time machine, should be different each time. see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date) for reference

Comment: You may want to take a look at [reproducible builds](https://github.com/dotnet/reproducible-builds)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is correct, a timestamp is stored in the PE Header of the built assembly.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, if that's the case, is there a way that I can shut it off. I think it's a very stupid decision, since as much as I know, determinisim is a key to create reliable CI/CD pipelines.

Comment: @HosseinFallah i don't think it's a stupid decision. at least it's smarter than storing binaries inside a git repo. you should instead store it as an artifact - should be trivial if you're using CI/CD. also: if you need it to stay the same, just don't _rebuild_ it unless the code base changed?

Comment: Roslyn supports [deterministic builds](https://gist.github.com/aelij/b20271f4bd0ab1298e49068b388b54ae)

Comment: @KlausGütter, excelletn link. Thank you. I used `<Deterministic>True</Deterministic>` in my `.csproj` file and that solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Thanks for the link.  The non-determinism of PE files produced by .NET compilers has been a bugaboo forever.  I know that Microsoft produced a tool way back when that would do a binary compare of two PE files that excluded the bits that changed on every build.  It was essential in some regulated industries.  As far as I know, it was never widely available (you needed a Premier Support contract and an inquisitive TAM or ADC to get access).  This is great to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize the comments, so that there's an answer here (OP should probably have done this): **Git says the file is modified because it is in fact modified.**  There is a build timestamp (in this case it is just a timestamp; other situations in other systems may include additional items) that makes the build not [*reproducible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds) or [*deterministic*](https://gist.github.com/aelij/b20271f4bd0ab1298e49068b388b54ae.).

This is a pretty common problem.  Some systems have a knob you can set to get deterministic builds, and this particular system did.  Turning it on solved the problem.  See [the link](https://gist.github.com/aelij/b20271f4bd0ab1298e49068b388b54ae.) provided in [Klaus Gütter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306369/why-my-dll-files-inside-are-being-marked-as-modified-in-git#comment124281955_70306369).